# inserting data into a table concurrently - hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, concurrency, insert, tomcat6

I have an application that uses hibernate to inert data into a table.
Database is SQL server. The application itself is deployed in Tomcat 6.
To insert data into DB table - I am using BasicDataSource with minimum configurations for tomcat connection pool (like MaxActive=150, maxIdle =10....)

The problem now is that - I want to add concurrency to the application. In the process - I am making concurrent calls to the business layer method that calls the dao level methods that perform DB inserts. This is resulting in the below error:

```
Exception occurred java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

When I monitor the database, I see that multiple threads are being created but are not being closed.

I am not sure how to proceed further to debug/fix this. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Start by reading the stack trace, and understand what you're doing in the code appearing in the stack trace. There is a bug in YOUR code.

Comment: How do you manage transactions and database connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Hibernate is telling you:

```
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

Basically you are opening two sessions, and have a transaction each and you are trying to save a session in one transaction into another. Ya concurrency is you major problem here. Well That can be tackled if you design your application so as to handle sessions carefully.
Stack-Trace will give you which functions are causing the exceptions. See how long you unit of work lasts with sessions and try reducing those and make sure your sessions are always closed after use.

An application implemented in hibernate can have various patterns.

> You need to have  ***session-per-request*** pattern. In this model, a
>   request from the client is sent to the server, where the Hibernate
>   persistence layer runs. A new Hibernate Session is opened, and all
>   database operations are executed in this unit of work. On completion
>   of the work, and once the response for the client has been prepared,
>   the session is flushed and closed. Use a single database transaction
>   to serve the clients request, starting and committing it when you open
>   and close the Session. The relationship between the two is one-to-one
>   and this model is a perfect fit for many applications

```
Do not use the anti-patterns session-per-user-session or session-per-application
```

The [Transaction And Concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) in **Hibernate Documentation** gives in depth analysis and examples